# ATtiny85 serial communication with multiple inputs

Tags: serial-communication, arduino-uno, attiny, software-serial

In a project, we try to set up a communication network between three ATtinys, where the first must receive messages from the other two. Those other two tinys are connected to two different pins of the first tiny. The first tiny must then receive two strings from the other tinys, one from each, and send it to an Arduino. For the communication we used `SoftwareSerial`. We managed to receive and send the input from one tiny, but not from both of them, because we could not find a way to read the input from only one specific pin at a time. 
This is the code we used:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
const int rx=4;
const int rx2=1;
const int tx=3;
const int tx2=3;

SoftwareSerial mySerial(rx,tx);
SoftwareSerial mySerial2(rx2,tx2);

void setup() 
{ 
  pinMode(rx,INPUT);
  pinMode(rx2,INPUT);
  pinMode(tx,OUTPUT);

  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial2.begin(9600);
} 

void loop()
{
  mySerial.listen();

  if (mySerial.isListening()) {
    mySerial.println("Port One is listening!"); 
    mySerial.println(mySerial.read());
  }
  else{
    mySerial.println("Port One is not listening!"); 
  }

  mySerial2.listen();
  if (mySerial2.isListening()) {
    mySerial2.println("Port Two is listening!"); 
    mySerial2.println(mySerial2.read());
  }
  else{
    mySerial2.println("Port Two is not listening!"); 
  }

  delay(500);

}
```

The code above worked without the part after `mySerial2.listen();`. Maybe the `listen`-function of `SoftwareSerial` does not work on the tinys, but if that is the case, is there another way to listen to a specific input pin? 
Or do you have any advice what to do?

Comment: Why not use the USI with multiple masters?

Comment: Thanks! I do not know much about this, but if we do that, we need more than one wire between the tinys, right? I forgot to mention this, but each tiny is located in its own "box" and we would like to have not more than one data connection/wire between the boxes. Therefore, a software solution for this problem would be optimal. Otherwise we (think that we) could use transistors/multiplexers to get the input of just one tiny at a time.

Comment: You probably want to read AVR274 then.